# R - Long Format Loop increment 1 by id and day

Tags: r, loops, increment, rcpp

I am facing an issue of a simple problem. 
The data I have contain the following variables :`BCSID id DD MM DAY`. 
The personal identifier, an id-day idenfifier, the calendar day, the calendar month and the day of the week. `DD_flag` is a variable that I need to create in order to correct the `DD` date that are wrong because they do not increment according to the day `DAY`.

My data look like this

```
      BCSID       id DD MM DAY
200 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
201 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
202 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
203 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
204 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
205 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
206 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2
207 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
208 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
209 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
210 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
211 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
212 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
213 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
214 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3
```

I will create my `DD_flag` variable based on `DD`

```
dtadate$DD_flag <- as.numeric(dtadate$DD)
```

What I need to do is to simply increment **+1** to th `DD_flag` variable each time the day `DAY` change for each identifier `BCSID`.

I thought that it could be simpler to use the collapsed id `id` for my loop.

**1**

I tried a R loop but 
I am not sure why this solution is wrong

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dtadate)){
  if( dtadate$id[i] == dtadate$id[i-1] )
  { dtadate$DD_flag[i] = dtadate$DD_flag[i] + 1 }
}
```

**2**

I tried a `Rcpp` solution, that almost gives me the correct output. 
Here I used the `BCSID` and the `DAY`.

The incrementation is correct but unfortunately is does not re-use the incremented value for the rest of the loop.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]] 
NumericVector TimeAddOneCpp(CharacterVector idDay, CharacterVector Day, NumericVector time) {

  int n = idDay.size();
  int len = n ; 

  for ( int i = 1; i < len; ++i ) {
    if( ( idDay[i] == idDay[i - 1] ) & 
        ( Day[i] != Day [i - 1] )
        )
      time[i] = time[i-1] + 1; 
  }

  return time;
}
```

The function

```
TimeAddOneCpp(idDay = dtadate$BCSID, Day = dtadate$DAY, time = dtadate$DD_flag)
```

**Expected output**

The output I want is the following

```
      BCSID       id DD MM DAY DD_flag
200 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
201 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
202 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
203 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
204 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
205 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
206 B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
207 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
208 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
209 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
210 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
211 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
212 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
213 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
214 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
215 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
216 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
217 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
218 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
219 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
220 B10011Q B10011Q4 24 10   4      26
...
```

So each time the `DAY` change for each `BCSID`, the `DD_flag` based on `DD` should be incremented by **+1**.

The data

```
dta = structure(list(BCSID = c("B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", 
                     "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10011Q", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", "B10015U", 
                     "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", 
                     "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", 
                     "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", "B10017W", 
                     "B10017W"), id = c("B10011Q2", "B10011Q2", "B10011Q2", "B10011Q2", 
                                        "B10011Q2", "B10011Q2", "B10011Q2", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", 
                                        "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", 
                                        "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q3", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", 
                                        "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", 
                                        "B10011Q4", "B10011Q4", "B10011Q5", "B10011Q5", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", 
                                        "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", 
                                        "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U1", "B10015U2", 
                                        "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", 
                                        "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", 
                                        "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U2", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", 
                                        "B10015U3", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", "B10015U3", 
                                        "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", 
                                        "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", "B10015U4", 
                                        "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", 
                                        "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", 
                                        "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", "B10017W1", 
                                        "B10017W1"), DD = c("24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", 
                                                            "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", 
                                                            "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", 
                                                            "24", "24", "24", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                                            "1", "1", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", 
                                                            "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13"), 
           MM = c("10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                  "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                  "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                  "10", "10", "10", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
                  "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
                  "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
                  "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
                  "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
                  "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
                  "6"), DAY = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                                "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", 
                                "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "1", 
                                "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
                                "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), .Names = c("BCSID", 
                                                                                     "id", "DD", "MM", "DAY"), row.names = 200:300, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You cut off the desired output after 6 rows. Can you extend it please so we can see at least the first 15 rows?

Comment: Ok it looks like you're grouping by month. You may need `dtadate %>% group_by(MM)  %>% mutate(DD_flag = c(0,cumsum(diff(DD)))+DD)`

Comment: I just simply want to increment by 1 when the day, already contained in the id, change.

Comment: The id changes in each row. they are all unique. For example, the row with `B10015U3 1 8 3 1` you didn't do thr the addition. Why not?

Comment: The id doesnt not change in each row. If you want the personal id is `B10015U` and `3` - `4` and so on... is the day actually.

Comment: That's what I thought, you have an id column with mixed variables. Why didn't you include in your question that the ids have extra numbers attached to them?

Comment: I thought it would make it simpler. But apparently not, so I will edit the question with this remark

Comment: It's okay. So the first ID is "B10011Q"?

Comment: @PierreLafortune - made major edits - tell me if its better now

Comment: I added a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% 
  group_by(BCSID) %>% 
  mutate(DD_flag = c(0, cumsum(diff(as.integer(DAY))))+as.integer(DD))

# Source: local data frame [101 x 6]
# Groups: BCSID
# 
#      BCSID       id DD MM DAY DD_flag
# 1  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 2  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 3  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 4  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 5  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 6  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 7  B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
# 8  B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
# 9  B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
# 10 B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
# ..     ...      ... .. .. ...     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create the desired values for DD_flag outside the original object, then merge them in. Let's call the data frame you posted z. So:

```
flags <- data.frame(id = unique(z$id), DD_flag = seq(length(unique(z$id))))
z2 <- merge(z, flags, all.x = TRUE)
```

That approach assumes that you don't care about the order of those flags. If you do, you just need to put the unique values of the id variable in the desired order in or before that first line.

That approach also assumes that you don't already have a variable named DD_flag in z when you go to merge. If you do, you could just run this before the merge:

```
z$DD_flag <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)
out = rbindlist(
      lapply(split(dta, dta$BCSID), 
      function(x){ x[, DD_flag := (as.numeric(x$DD) + .GRP)-1, by = DAY]}))

 #> out
 #     BCSID       id DD MM DAY DD_flag
 #1: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #2: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #3: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #4: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #5: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #6: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #7: B10011Q B10011Q2 24 10   2      24
 #8: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
 #9: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#10: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#11: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#12: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#13: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#14: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#15: B10011Q B10011Q3 24 10   3      25
#...
```